# visual studio cordova deploy to ios device failing and visual studio crashing

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am having issues deploying my cordova app to an ios device.

The ios device is iphone 4 on ios version 7.1.2 which is the maximum for iphone 4.

I am using visual studio community edition 2015 with update 1 on my windows 10 machine. My project is running version 6.1.1 of cordova.

I have followed all the instructions on what needs to be installed on my mac which is running El Capitan OS. I have node version 4.5 running on my windows 10 machine and on the mac machine. I have my iphone connected to the mac.

The remotebuild is running fine on my mac and the process gets as far as the deploy step and then after a while a 404 shows up in the remotebuild output window on my mac and visual studio comes back with a failure saying - failed to deploy ios remote build on "my servername". It then crashes.

log from remotebuild server on mac:.....

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 1.325 ms - 715

Extracted app contents from uploaded build request to /Users/johngobl/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/2716/cordovaApp. Requesting build.

Taking 2716 as current build

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 1.361 ms - 777

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.857 ms - 777

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 1.068 ms - 777

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.788 ms - 777

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.707 ms - 778

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.838 ms - 778

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.698 ms - 778

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.848 ms - 778

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.717 ms - 778

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 1.268 ms - 778

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.679 ms - 778

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.577 ms - 778

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.755 ms - 778

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.900 ms - 776

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.643 ms - 776

Done with current build. Checking for next build in queue.

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716 200 0.695 ms - 757

GET /cordova/build/tasks/2716/log 200 2088.906 ms - -

GET /cordova/files/2716/cordovaApp/plugins/ios.json 200 2.277 ms - 756

GET /cordova/build/2716/download 200 5496.345 ms - -

GET /cordova/build/2716/deploy 404 154426.165 ms - 573

log in visual studio output window:.....

2>------ Deploy started: Project: TestCordovaApp, Configuration: Debug iOS ------
2>  ------ Cordova tools 6.1.1 already installed.
2>  Requesting deploy on remote iOS device for buildNumber 2716 on server "my server name".

Am I missing something or is it not possible to deploy to iphone 4 devices? Any help greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ios device is iphone 4 on ios version 7.1.2 which is the maximum for iphone 4.

The minimum iOS Version supported as of cordova 4.0.0 is iOS 8.

Please refer to [Requirements and Support](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer. forgot to check the cordova site for such details.